# MAAS Network question - Node cannot ping to outside world (ip shows up correctly)

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, wakeonlan

Hello AskUbuntu community,

For the past few days, I finally jumped on the MAAS train but encountered a few problems with network configurations. I do apologize if I have missed some fundamental concepts asmy knowledge in networking is rather limited to small networks. My cluster, region controllers, dhcp, dns reside on the same ip: 10.0.0.1 connected via eth0. The Internet connected ip is 192.168.0.81 connected via wlan0. Both interfaces are added to the cluster interfaces and network (am I suppose to do this?)

I tried to follow the guides but I still cannot resolve these problems

1.) Juju bootstrap failed with
curl: (7) Failed to connect to streams.canonical.com port 443

- Pinging from nodes via ssh yield outside world's ip but the packet is lost
- Firewalls are disabled - `sudo ufw disable`

This is my current /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

MAAS ip configures (dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster & region) are both on 10.0.0.1 and `http://10.0.0.1/MAAS`

2.) Wake-On-LAN doesn't work properly (I suspect it is due to Network)
I followed [Daniel's method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504452/node-in-maas-not-waking-up-on-lan) and was only able to startup the machines by typing in `"sudo etherwake $mac_address"` not through the cluster control panel

[Relevant Screenshots](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B423f7g0PpNwWWpnZ1VUTHFMc2s/view?usp=sharing) - (Sorry, new users are limited to 2 links per post limitation)

Comment: 1.) Resolved with IPv4 NAT
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: can you write this up as an answer so that it can be a bit more useful for the next person? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still working on etherwake but for the moment I have figured a few things out about how MAAS works. I was correct about editing the cluster interfaces with the ifconfig from the machine that runs it. However, what I didn't know was that I have to forward the traffic from IPv4 to the internal LAN as well. In this case, I connect to the internet via wlan0 and my internal is connected via eth0. So, this is how I forward my traffic.

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav
```

Add this line into /etc/rc.local before exit 0 line

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav
```

Edit /etc/sysctl.conf (remove # from #net.ipv4.ip_forward=1) then

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Note: I'm still working on Etherwake problem. Any pointers are highly appreciated.